# Wrap python argument for pybind11 overloaded methods

Tags: python, c++, pybind11

I'm trying to create python bindings for some legacy C++ code which implemented its own 'extended' string class `aString` which it uses extensively. This works fine for `.def(py::init<const std::string &, int>())`, but once I start trying to wrap overloaded methods pybind11 does not appear to automatically cast `std::string` to `aString`. MWE adapted from the pybind11 docs:

`src/example.cpp`:

```cpp
#include <pybind11/pybind11.h>

// Extended string class and struct in legacy library
class aString : public std::string
{
public:
    aString() : std::string() {}
    aString(const char *str) : std::string(str) {}
    aString(const std::string &str) : std::string(str) {}
};

struct Pet
{
    Pet(const aString &name, int age) : name(name), age(age) {}

    void set(int age_) { age = age_; }
    void set(const aString &name_) { name = name_; }

    aString name;
    int age;
};

// Python bindings
namespace py = pybind11;

PYBIND11_MODULE(example, m)
{
    py::class_<aString>(m, "aString")
        .def(py::init<const std::string &>())
        .def("__repr__",
             [](const aString &a)
             {
                 return "<aString ('" + a + "')>";
             });

    py::class_<Pet>(m, "Pet")
        .def(py::init<const std::string &, int>())
        .def("set", static_cast<void (Pet::*)(int)>(&Pet::set), "Set the pet's age")
        .def("set", static_cast<void (Pet::*)(const aString &)>(&Pet::set), "Set the pet's name")
        .def("__repr__",
             [](const Pet &a)
             {
                 return "<Pet ('" + a.name + "')>";
             });
    ;
}
```

`CMakeLists.txt`:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.4)
project(example)
add_subdirectory(pybind11)
pybind11_add_module(example src/example.cpp)
```

In python, the following works fine:

```py
import example
p = example.Pet("Penny", 1)
p.set(3)
a = example.aString("Anne")
p.set(a)
```

However, the following fails with the message:

```
#> p.set("Jenny")
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-9-c5b0ff7c5315> in <module>
----> 1 p.set("Jenny")

TypeError: set(): incompatible function arguments. The following argument types are supported:
    1. (self: example.Pet, arg0: int) -> None
    2. (self: example.Pet, arg0: example.aString) -> None

Invoked with: <Pet ('Anne')>, 'Jenny'
```

I've tried changing my pybinding to be `.def("set", static_cast<void (Pet::*)(const std::string &)>(&Pet::set), "Set the pet's name")` instead of `aString`, but this will not compile as `std::string` is not one of the overload instances. I cannot add an additional overload instance for `std:string` in the C++ library.

I would like to be able to call `p.set("Jenny")` and let pybind11 convert `"Jenny"` into `aString("Jenny")`, rather than `p.set(example.aString("Jenny"))`. This is my first project with pybind11 so any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can enable an [implicit conversion](https://pybind11.readthedocs.io/en/stable/advanced/classes.html#implicit-conversions) between types by adding the following statement:

```cpp
py::implicitly_convertible<std::string, aString>();
```

In general `py::implicitly_convertible<A, B>()` works only if (as in your case) `B` has a constructor that takes `A` as its only argument.

Comment: Awesome, works like a charm thank you! I was deep down a rabbit hole in docs and examples looking for argument wrapping, didn't think of searching for implicit conversion

Answer (score 1):

I've marked @lr1985's answer as correct, since it's the simplest solution for me - I don't need to manually convert each `std::string` to `aString` for each method call.

However, I did work out a solution if anyone absolutely has to wrap or add an overload of another type:

```cpp
py::class_<Pet>(m, "Pet")
    // ...
    .def("set",
        [](Pet &self, const std::string &s)
        {
            aString as = aString(s);
            self.set(as);
        });
```